# Normal bundle of a quotient map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I would like to know if there is a notion of normal bundle to a quotient map. In one specific case, let $G$ be a finite group acting on an algebraic variety $V$. Denote by the map $\pi:V \rightarrow V/G$ the quotient map. Is it possible to define the normal bundle to $\pi$ having good properties. For example, I would like to get the projection formula. If $V/G$ is a substack of $X$ of co-dimension $r,$ do we get a vector bundle of rank $r$ on $V$ as the normal bundle to the composition $V \rightarrow V/G \rightarrow X$?
I am interested in the case where $V/G$ is a Deligne-Mumford stack.

I would like to know the conditions under which the equality 
$$i^*(i_*(x))=x.c_r(N)$$ for $x\in A^*(V)$ holds.

Here, $N$ is the desired normal bundle. What is the condition under which the Chern classes of this bundle exist?

The question may not be stated correctly and clearly. I apologize about it.

Comment: Are you looking at the quotient " $V/G$ " as a GIT quotient V//G  or as a Deligne-Mumford stack [V/G] ?

Answer (score 2):

For *any* map $f:X\to Y$ of smooth stacks, you can define a virtual normal bundle $N_{X/Y}$ as $[f^*T_Y]-[T_X]$. That would be an element of the K-ring $K^*(X)$.

Comment: I like your name.